# Windows Sensors - Winforms vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, gps

need some assistance with getting started using windows geo location sensors and win froms

i have found this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.aspx

but every thing that i seem to find all relates to window phone or windows store i don't want to program in ether i have most of the application already written in win forms already.

i have a broadcom GPS GSS 4572 and i have worked out how to connect to the windows location servers but not the GPS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Device.Location;

namespace geo_c
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static string lon;
    public static string lat;

    static void gps()
    {
        GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher;
        watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();

        watcher.PositionChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var coordinate = e.Position.Location;
            Console.WriteLine("Lat: {0}, Long: {1}", coordinate.Latitude,
                coordinate.Longitude);
        lat = coordinate.Latitude.ToString();
        lon = coordinate.Longitude.ToString();

            // Uncomment to get only one event. 
            // watcher.Stop(); 

        };

        // Begin listening for location updates.
        watcher.Start();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gps();
        textBox1.Text = lon;
        textBox2.Text = lat;
    }



   }
 }
```

Comment: it seem that i have got it working the with the code but i have no way of selecting the gps as the preferred  device.